# How to do Column Select in Sublime using Touchpad?

Tags: sublimetext, touchpad

I'm very fond of the column select feature. But I find it limiting to not be able to do it using the touchpad (when I'm using a mac, for example, and have no mouse). I've done a lot of searching, but could not find this described anywhere. They just describe it the mouse-way and keyboard-way (like [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html)).

EDIT : This was confusing only because of the single button mac touchpad.

Comment: Hold down control and click on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe that I'd completely missed this simple method:

Press **Option + click and drag away** with the touchpad.